# Assign and keep track of user ids in firestore with distributed counter extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my Firestore collection "tracking_info" I have a single document called "tracking_info" where I hold "last_user_id" field which tracks the last registered user id.

After a user registers with Firebase Auth, I want to create a new user document in "users" collection and have a field "user_id", the value of which was taken from "last_user_id" and add 1 to it. After this, I want to increase the value of "last_user_id" in tracking_info.

I was able to do that but then realized that Firestore can only handle 1 write/update per second to a document. Although very unlikely, 2 users may register at the same second.

Then I read about the distributed counter and added it to "last_user_id" field to address the issue with several writes per second. However "last_user_id" will be updated only once a minute, therefore if other users could register with the same id as other users who registered in the same minute.

How can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing all user IDs into a single document, and you're afraid of the 1 write per second limitation, then you should consider creating multiple documents, rather than a single one. Since each addition of a UID inside the `tracking_info` document, it costs you one write, then you should consider writing a new document for each UID. Since reading the `tracking_info` document, it costs you one read, to have the same cost when using multiple documents, then you should follow these steps:

1. In each new document that you create you should add only two fields. The UID and a timestamp.

The schema should look like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- trackingInfo (collection)
        |
        --- docId (generated by Firestore)
             |
             --- uid: "veryLongId"
             |
             --- timestamp: September 30, 2022 at 2:46:19 PM UTC+3
```

2. Create a query and limit the result to 1. Since you didn't specify a tag with a programming language, I will provide the code in Java, as I've seen other questions of yours that are related to it.

Here is the Java code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query queryByTimestamp = db.collection("trackingInfo").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1);
queryByTimestamp.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document != null) {
                    String lastUserId = document.getString("uid");
                    Log.d(TAG, "uid: " + uid);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Using this approach, you'll be able to pay 1 read too.

Besides that, if you check the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#writes), it is said that:

> Sustaining a write rate above once per second increases latency and causes contention errors. This is not a hard limit, and you can surpass the limit in short bursts.

So surpassing the limit in short bursts, might also solve the problem.

If this approach is not what you want, although it solves your problem and no distributed counters are needed, then you should consider using the Realtime Database, where you can [write up to 1,000 writes/second per database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#writes).

Comment: Hey Joe. Have you tried my solution above, does it work? Or can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you for your reply. I like your solution! I guess I would need to implement some kind of sorting in that case, because documents don't follow any order as far as I remember. I was thinking about this and realized that this issue would also be solved if I use transactions? e.g. read "last_user_id", set user id and set last_user_id +1 to "tracking_info". This should cover 1 write per second rule as far as I understand, because if write fails, transaction will retry it?

Comment: In my answer above, I have already added a call to `.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1)` so you can always read the most recent one. I'm not sure why would you use a transaction, since each user will write the UID in a different document. I cannot see how you can have concurrent modifications.

Comment: If you want to implement any other logic that involves concurrent modifications, then using transactions is a solution to go ahead with. And yes, if a transaction fails, there is a retry mechanism present.